# quick print in c#

Tags: c#, printing

how can I print quickly without show print dialog just click on button and print in default printer ?

Comment: From a web forms application? Windows Forms? WPF? SilverLight? What?

Comment: WPF I am sorry I miss some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not printed in WPF, but I found the following (maybe it will help?):

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/printing-in-wpf

Answer (score 4):

For WinForms, use the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class and do not specify a printer, then it will print to the default printer.